# How to configure Cartographer_ROS to create new submaps when trajectory path elevates on Z axis?

Tags: dictionary, ros, lidar, slam

I have configured the cartographer_ros to run with my Ouster LiDAR according to configurations given in: [ouster_example/cartographer_ros](https://github.com/wilselby/ouster_example/blob/master/cartographer_ros/configuration_files/cart_3d.lua).

When I run the realtime/offline SLAM using the my LiDAR it starts to generate the ground level map perfectly and when I climb the stairs the trajectory path elevates along with the pointcloud data but it doesn't create a new submap at upper level, instead it starts to override (/overlay) the ground level map with new occupancy grid data. Below RVIZ screenshot shows the issue:

[image: issue in ouster config rivz map]

Does anyone know what parameters effect or what parameters I need to change to get it creating new submaps when the trajectory path elevates to a new level (/floor)?

The default demo that provided by the [Cartographer official documentation](https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demos.html) works well as shown in below screenshot. I need similar results with my Ouster LiDAR configurations. I tried copying the default config parameters to my config files but it had no luck. Also I tried checking the documentations to figure out the settings but had no luck and it is overwhelming due to so many configuration parameters. Any help to figure out what configurations affect the new submap creation when the trajectory elevates is much appreciated.

[image: Cartographer demo rviz map]